# Is there a function for set root in ionic 4?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

cannot set root page dynamically so that back button can be routed back to unwanted pages.
to Set root page dynamically like in ionic-3 `setroot()`

```
 this.app.getRootNav().setRoot(DrivernumberComponent);



this.navCtrl.push('FilmDetailsPage');
```

Answer (score 0):

Ionic 4 relies on Angular's router, the NavController has been changed to reflect this new reality, and for an Angular application there is no such a thing like "root" route. You simply transition between routes and the framework does the rest of the work.

> this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/DrivernumberComponent');

In your case you need to redirect route to your root that you want to move i.e. "DrivernumberComponent"